# Set content box 100% high but if the content only a few lins then without scrolling

Tags: html, css, height, overflow, containers

I have five div boxes: wrapper, header, navigation, content-title, content. The header and navigation has a fixed high and the content should always on the rest of the website (to bottom). My problem is that a vertical scrollbar everytime exist. This happens also if my content has only a few lines text.

I want that the scrollbar only appears if the content from the content div is to long for the website.

Demo:

1). Website with a few words: http://projekt-pythorion.de/Test/index.php

2). Website with many words: http://projekt-pythorion.de/Test/index_manywords.php

1 = Not correct because i dont want that scroll bar because the text is not so long but i want that my content div goes to bottom of the webpage.

2 = Correct because the text is to long and so i can scroll down.

Comment: It's because of the height setting on the content_box_background div...try scaling that back a tad.

Comment: You mean that i set the high from my content box to for example 80%? That dont work because that makes the box to short. I want that the box go always to the bottom of the webpage and the scroll bar oly appears if the content is to long.

Comment: I edit my first entry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I understood your question. But, if you need a scroll that will only appear if the content is larger than the container, then you are looking for `overflow: auto`.

Here's an example showing it working: http://jsfiddle.net/tnh9M/

**EDIT**

Now with your updated question it's possible to see the issue. Remove the `height: 100%` from `#content_box_background`, for it's making the document body overflow... If you want it to go to the bottom of the page, you have to calculate the 100% height, minus the top offset you are setting, like `height: calc(100% - 400px);`

Comment: Overflow:auto by the content_box dont work. Then i have a scrollbar in the div element. That looks not so good...

Comment: Actually, it's probably a bad structured html.. We really could use a demo... Can you make a http://jsfiddle.net ?